How to Increase TCP Server (serves a serial port over TCP ) throughput?
Description:
I am developing a TCP echo server that receives data from a TCP client, writes it to a serial port, and then reads the data back from the serial port to send it to the TCP client. For testing, I use a loopback connector (/dev/ttyUSB0). This server is just for practicing!
This is also a burnin application serverd as TCP client which send data to our server and calculate the throughputs.
The current throughput is approximately 72KB/s, and I aim to increase it to 80KB/s. Here is a brief overview of my server’s functionality and setup:

The server listens for incoming TCP connections and handles them using a non-blocking socket.
Data received from the TCP client is written to a serial port.
Data read from the serial port is sent back to the TCP client.
I have implemented high/low watermarks for controlling when to pause or resume writing to the serial port. (Since the difference of throughput between TCP and serial)

However, I am struggling to achieve the desired throughput.

Questions:

What strategies or optimizations can I apply to increase the server's throughput?
Are there any potential bottlenecks in my current implementation?
Are there more efficient ways to handle the serial port and TCP connection to improve performance?


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
 
#define BACK_LOG 5
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8192
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 2048
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
 
typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;
typedef struct tcp_info
{
    int fd;
    sockaddr_in socket_address;
} tcp_info;
 
void tcp_destroy_server(tcp_info *tcp_server)
{
    if (tcp_server == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
 
    close(tcp_server->fd);
    free(tcp_server);
}
 
tcp_info *tcp_create_server(const char *ip_addr, int port)
{
    tcp_info *tcp_server;
    int yes = 1;
 
    if (ip_addr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
 
    if ((tcp_server = calloc(1, sizeof(tcp_info))) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
 
    tcp_server->socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);
    tcp_server->socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_addr, &(tcp_server->socket_address.sin_addr));
 
    if ((tcp_server->fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to create socket!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
 
    if (setsockopt(tcp_server->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Set socket option failed");
        close(tcp_server->fd);
        return NULL;
    }
 
    if (bind(tcp_server->fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&tcp_server->socket_address, sizeof(tcp_server->socket_address)) == -1)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to bind socket!\n");
        close(tcp_server->fd);
        return NULL;
    }
 
    if (listen(tcp_server->fd, BACK_LOG) == -1)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to listen!\n");
        close(tcp_server->fd);
        return NULL;
    }
 
    return tcp_server;
}
 
int serial_open_port(const char *serial_port)
{
    int serial_fd = -1;
    struct termios tty = {0};
 
    if (serial_port == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
 
    if ((serial_fd = open(serial_port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC | O_NDELAY)) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
 
    if (tcgetattr(serial_fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error from tcgetattr");
        close(serial_fd);
        return -1;
    }
 
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B921600);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B921600);
 
    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;
    tty.c_lflag = 0;
    tty.c_oflag = 0;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
 
    if (tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error from tcsetattr");
        close(serial_fd);
        return -1;
    }
 
    return serial_fd;
}
 
// receiving buffer
int get_serial_input_buffer_size(int fd)
{
    int bytes_available = -1;
 
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCINQ, &bytes_available) == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl TIOCINQ error");
        return -1;
    }
 
    return bytes_available;
}
 
// sending buffer
int get_serial_output_buffer_size(int fd)
{
    int bytes_available = -1;
 
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCOUTQ, &bytes_available) == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl TIOCOUTQ error");
        return -1;
    }
 
    return bytes_available;
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <IP> <PORT> <SERIAL PORT>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    /* Server configuration */
    const char *server_address = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);
    const char *serial_port = argv[3];
 
    /* Define variables */
    tcp_info *tcp_server;
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    char socket_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char serial_buffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    bool enable_write = true;
 
    int client_fd = -1;
    int serial_fd = -1;
    int serial_written = 0;
    int serial_offset = 0;
 
    if ((tcp_server = tcp_create_server(server_address, port)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("[ERROR] failed to create TCP server");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    if ((serial_fd = serial_open_port(serial_port)) == -1)
    {
        perror("[ERROR] failed to open serial");
        tcp_destroy_server(tcp_server);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    printf("[INFO] Server waiting for connections.........\n");
    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
 
    if ((client_fd = accept(tcp_server->fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_len)) == -1)
    {
        perror("[ERROR] Failed to aceept a new socket connection");
        tcp_destroy_server(tcp_server);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    printf("[INFO] Accept a connection from tcp \n");
 
    fd_set read_fds;
    fcntl(client_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
 
    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        FD_SET(client_fd, &read_fds);
        FD_SET(serial_fd, &read_fds);
 
        if (select(MAX(serial_fd, client_fd) + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror("select() error");
            break;
        }
 
        /* Read data from socket , then writing to the serial port */
        if (enable_write && FD_ISSET(client_fd, &read_fds))
        {
            int valread = recv(client_fd, socket_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
 
            if (valread <= 0)
            {
                perror("[ERROR] Socket recv error");
                break;
            }
 
            int write_num = write(serial_fd, socket_buffer, valread);
           
            if (write_num < 0)
            {
                perror("[ERROR] Write to serial error");
                break;
            }
            else if(write_num != valread)
            {
                perror("write num != valread");
                break;
            }
           
        }
       
        /* high/low watermark */
        int val = get_serial_output_buffer_size(serial_fd);
        if (val >= 23000)
        {
            enable_write = false; // stop writing data to serial
        }
        else if (val <= 1000)
        {
            //printf("val size = %d", val);
            enable_write = true;
        }
 
        /* Read data from serial */
        if (FD_ISSET(serial_fd, &read_fds))
        {  
            int read_num = read(serial_fd, serial_buffer + serial_offset, SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE - serial_offset);
 
            if (read_num <= 0)
            {
                perror("[ERROR] Read from serial");
                break;
            }
 
            serial_offset += read_num;
 
            if (serial_offset == SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                if (send(client_fd, serial_buffer, SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE, 0) == -1)
                {
                    perror("[ERROR] Socket send error");
                    break;
                }
                printf("socket send %d bytes\n", SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
                serial_offset = 0;
            }
        }
    }
 
    tcp_destroy_server(tcp_server);
    return 0;
}


Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve the target throughput would be greatly appreciated.
I have implemented high/low watermarks to control the writing frequency to the serial port, but I am still unable to achieve the desired throughput.

When you say 80KB/sec, do you mean 80,000 or 80*1024? (When talking about communication, K is usually interpreted as base 10, but I wanted to make sure.)

Have you measured the individual communication speeds? When you modify the program to only read from the TCP connection, and not write to the TCP connection or read or write the serial port, what is the speed? What about writing to the TCP connection? Reading the serial port? Writing the serial port? Both reading and writing the serial port?

@StreveFord Why does it matter whether it's 1000 or 1024 in this case? It's the same order of magnitude.

@Barmar I wanted to calculate the maximum theoretical throughput for it, and I wanted to use the same units. Yes, for approximation, they are the same. I wanted an upper limit.

@StreveFord 80KB/sec = 80,000 Bytes/sec in this case.

"The current throughput is ..." - So you're using about 78% of the serial bandwidth, and you want to up that to 87%?!?! Are you validating this data after it makes a round-trip? In the main loop, after the select() returns, the order of handling FD_ISSET()s is backwards. The serial_fd needs to be checked first, so that a read() can (try to) empty the termios buffer before another serial transfer can occur. BTW your termios initialization is inconsistent; see Setting Terminal Modes Properly.

Your program receives a TCP message of some unknown size, but only/always sends a TCP message of SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE or 2048 bytes. Why? IIRC that may require 2 TCP segments, one full and one fraction of a full segment. The value for SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE seems arbitrary. Why not make it 1448, which is the TCP Maximum Segment Size, or a safer 1380 bytes? See https://superuser.com/questions/1341012/practical-vs-theoretical-max-limit-of-tcp-packet-size

@sawdust yes i want to up that to 87%.
The reason for setting SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE is because i want to reduce times about calling send(). I will try to reduce to 1380bytes later.

Whenever the read(serial_fd,...) returns exactly the requested count, the possibility exists that there is still more data available. Since Ethernet is faster than the serial port and your use "watermarks" to throttle serial writes, you could improve a potential bottleneck in the FD_ISSET(serial_fd, ...) handling by always reading all available bytes, rather than just enough to fill the serial_buffer.

When the FD_ISSET(serial_fd, ...) is triggered, it contains roughly 500 bytes could be read.  So I try to buffer them into serial_buffer until read SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE chars.

I assume that the serial link is the bottle neck, and enable_write is false most of the time.
When enable_write is false and client_fd is readable, then the while loop is busy. select() returns immediately until there is noting to read from client_fd.
It might have effect on performance. At least it use lot of CPU time.
Simple fix for this:
Don't set client_fd to read_fd-set when enable_write is false.
